# Angularjs 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have code like this:

```
$scope.flags = [];

$scope.$watch('selectedFilter', function() {    
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                $scope.flags.push(i);
            }    
    });

$scope.$watch('flags', function(oldval, newval) {

                    if (oldval != newval) {

                        console.log("hello");
                    }

                });
```

But I get error:

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Why is this ? And how can I come around this problem ?
Note this is oversimplification of what I am trying to do :)

Comment: take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376879/error-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-with-dynamic-sortby-predicate

Answer (score 3):

One thing I want to point out is when you watch the change of a list, you should set the 3rd parameter to `true`.

```
$scope.$watch('flags', function (oldval, newval) {
    if (oldval != newval) {
        console.log("hello");
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: can you explain **why**?

Comment: @simonlchilds The full signarture of $watch is $watch(watchFn, watchAction, deepWatch). The third parameter _deepWatch_ if set, means for Angular: examine **each** property within the object for changes.